# How to use OR condition in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to use the formula below to set conditions in LibreOffice but I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong with the statement below:

=IF(G2<=2,'negative',IF(OR(G2>2 & G2<=3,'neutral',IF(OR(G2>=4,'positive))))))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that in your formula is missing the last `'`:

> 'positive))))))

should be `'positive'))))))`

Also the

> &

is string-concatenation in LibreOffice, so you need here the equivalent to `OR()` and that is `AND()`.

But you can simplify your formula to

> =IF(G2<=2,'negative',IF(AND(G2>2,G2<=3),'neutral','positive'))

The first test is if the number is lower than 2 (negative),
the second test is if the number is between 2 and 3 (neutral)
and then there is no further test needed as it is the only remainig possiblity.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply but it still doesn't work with the corrected one below. I am getting the #Name error
=IF(G2<=2,'negative',IF(OR(G2>2&G2<=3,'neutral',IF(OR(G2>=4,'positive')))))

Comment: thanks, tried your formula but still the same error #NAME? appears

Comment: @MugB It's a little bit difficult as I don't know your localization. I have only a german LO. For me `=WENN(G2<=2;"negative";WENN(UND(G2>2;G2<=3);"neutral";"positive"))` works. I don't know if you have to use `"` instead of `'` and `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: wow.. im in germany too and looks like it worked with your last solution! Danke schon!!

Comment: gerne! schon tag :)

Answer (score 0):

For a different locale, a slightly shorter, and I'd say simpler, version that also avoids the need for OR/AND:

```
=IF(G2<=2,"negative",IF(G2<=3,"neutral","positive"))
```

Once `<=2` first test is handled (either but outputting `negative` or by proceeding to the 'result if FALSE') there is no longer the possibility of `2` or less, so the AND is not necessary.

The above though does fill a gap left by OP between `3` and `4`.